# Qual è la differenza tra aviazione e aeronautica?

Tags: difference

Le due parole esistono in parallelo, dunque hanno diverso significato. Qual è la differenza tra aviazione e aeronautica?

Comment: +1, domanda interessante. Poi, in generale non è sempre detto che, per il fatto che esistono due parole, abbiano significato diverso. Potrebbe essere diverso il registro d'uso, la diffusione regionale o storica, o vari altri fattori: pensa a proseguire/seguitare/continuare o, fra i termini tecnici, nonio e verniero.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Il termine **Aviazione** è stato creato intendendolo come un derivato del termine lat. *avis* ("uccello") con l'aggiunta del suffisso *-tio*, che contraddistingue i *nomina actionis*: sostituendo metonimicamente "volo" a "uccello" si avrebbe così "l'azione del volo". La sua coniazione "risale a due persone, il visconte de Ponton d'Amécourt, che aveva pensato al lat. *avis*, ma ne aveva tratto un non accettabile *ef* (secondo il modello di *nef* da *navis*) e Joseph Gabriel de la Landelle, che da *avis* trasse aviation in una conferenza del 1863; e similmente aviateur" (B. Migliorini, *Lingua d'oggi e di ieri*, Caltanissetta-Roma 1973, p. 56; vd. anche G. Boffito, *Origine e vicenda di alcune voci attinenti al volo*, "Studi di Filologia Italiana" 6, 1942, pp. 201-203).

**Aeronautica** è un composto formato da due vocaboli di origine greca  ἀήρ ("aria", lat. *aer*), e ναυτική (sc. τέχνη, ossia "arte della navigazione", lat. *nautica*) probabilmente per il tramite dei corrispettivi latini. Per quanto riguarda la prima attestazione del termine, sappiamo che esso "si trova per la prima volta nominato, sebbene all'aggettivo, nell'espressione *ars aeronautica* già nel 1695, cioè 88 anni prima che un aeromobile fosse lanciato in aria. Fu un erudito tedesco, Giorgio Pasch, che in un suo libro in latino intitolato *De novis inventis quorum accuratiori cultui facem praetulit antiquitas*, la oppose ad un'altra arte, non dico più nota, ma per lo meno già nominata, l'*ars volandi*" (R. Giacomelli, *Evoluzione della terminologia aeronautica*, "Lingua Nostra" 13, 1952, p. 6).

Sebbene nell'uso comune non si sia affermata una netta demarcazione semantica, considerando la differente derivazione etimologica è tuttavia corretto desumere che i termini aviazione e aeronautica possano riferirsi rispettivamente all'atto del volare e dunque all'**aeromobile** in sé e alla **navigazione aerea**, come d'altronde appare evidente nelle definizioni del *Dizionario della lingua italiana* a c. di T. De Mauro (Torino 2000):

**Aviazione:**

> - 1 scienza e tecnica relative alla progettazione, alla costruzione e all'uso di aeromobili;
> - 2 insieme dei velivoli civili e militari di uno Stato e dei servizi e del personale adibiti al loro funzionamento: aviazione civile,
>     militare

**Aeronautica:**

> - 1a il complesso delle attività organizzative, scientifiche, tecniche e di progettazione relative alla navigazione aerea;
> - 2a l'insieme di enti, persone e mezzi relativi all'attività aerea: aeronautica civile, aeronautica militare;
> - 2b con iniz. maiusc.: il corpo militare a cui è affidata la difesa aerea del territorio.

Comment: +1, grazie per l'ampia trattazione storica. Vedo che poi la distinzione etimologica si è andata un po' confondendo (come suggeriscono già le definizioni del De Mauro). L'aeronautica militare include anche e soprattutto i mezzi, mentre viceversa l'ENAC, Ente Nazionale per l'Aviazione Civile, si occupa di molto più che solo gli aeromobili: regolamenta le procedure degli aeroporti, certifica il “personale che esercita in ambito aeronautico e nella navigazione aerea” (licenze di pilotaggio etc.) e così via. [segue]

Comment: [segue] E per “aviazione generale” si intendono, non specificamente gli aerei, ma tutte le attività di volo civili non commerciali (turismo, sport etc.).

Comment: Sì, effettivamente nell'uso comune i due termini sono impiegati in maniera affine, anche se come hai osservato aeronautica designa più spesso la componente militare. Sarebbe interessante consultare un dizionario storico come il *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana* a c. di S. Battaglia in merito, nel quale saranno sicuramente registrate ulteriori informazioni sull'introduzione ed evoluzione dei due termini in Italia.

Answer (score -1):

Il sito [Manualedivolo](http://www.manualedivolo.it/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=815:aeronautica-o-aviazione&catid=35:generale&Itemid=57) sembra dare una spiegazione molto accurata e storica in riferimento alla questione.

Comment: Prima di rispondere, potresti per piacere dare un'occhiata alle [faq](http://italian.stackexchange.com/help) di questo sito? Per esempio, al fatto che «Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.»

Comment: Non ho capito perché @xxxxxx abbia cancellato la propria risposta, che menzionava lo stesso sito, ma con una risposta più completa. (Per inciso, xxxxxx o momomorez sanno che sito sia e se sia attendibile?)

Answer (score -1):

> Aviazione: Studio degli aeromobili e annesse applicazioni tecnologiche

MENTRE:

> Aeronautica: Scienza e tecnica di costruzione e impiego degli aerei.

Credo che la differenza sia evidente per definizione e potremmo quasi dire che la prima comprende in toto la seconda.

Comment: Puoi citare una fonte, per piacere?

Comment: cit. dizionari.repubblica.it ma anche su wikipedia puoi trovare analoghe definizioni

Comment: Grazie, ma a parte dove le posso trovare io (e non certo su Wikipedia), una risposta deve citare le proprie fonti (link a un sito o estremi bibliografici di un testo).

Comment: E a parte tutto, qualcuno dovrebbe avvertire l'aeronautica militare italiana, che pensa di far parte delle forze armate e di svolgere missioni militari, che invece si occupa solo di scienza e tecnica.